# react-bootstrap-typeahead TypeScript- Ref - getInstance does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap-typeahead

Im using react-bootstrap-typeahead typescript, added types from `@types/react-bootstrap-typeahead`

In my typeahead from react functional component, I'm trying to access the typeahead ref and call the public methods of the component, as given [here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Methods.md)

import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

```
const typeahead = React.createRef();

<Typeahead
ref={(ref) => typeahead = ref}
id="basic-typeahead-single"
filterBy={['dialCode', 'name']}
inputProps={{
    className: 'attrib',
}}
labelKey={(option: any) => `${option.name}`}
onChange={(selected: any) => {
    console.log(selected);
}}
renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
    <div>
        <div>{option.name}   {option.section}</div>
    </div>
)}
options={employeeList}
selected={state.internationalization}>
</Typeahead>
<span className="arrow" onClick={() => {
    const instance = typeahead.getInstance();
    console.log("instance", instance);
    instance.clear();
    instance.focus();
}}><img src="/arrow.svg" /></span>
```

It throws error - Property 'getInstance' does not exist on type 'RefObject'

so while creating ref I tried:  `const typeahead = React.createRef<Typeahead>();`
But it seems something is missing for typescript

Answer (score 3):

The variable `typeahead` which you created from `createRef` is a `RefObject` with a property `current` that references your component.

When you create the ref, you need to specify the component type with the generic.  As you saw, the `Typeahead` class is itself generic, but the generic type doesn't matter for what you are trying to do, so you can use `any` to say that it is a ref to a `Typeahead` component with any type of data.

```
const typeahead = React.createRef<Typeahead<any>>();
```

Since we are using the new `createRef` syntax instead of the older callback refs, when you pass the ref to the component you just pass the whole ref object.

```
<Typeahead ref={typeahead} ... />
```

To access the instance, you look at the `.current` property of the ref, which is either `null` or `Typeahead<any>`.

```
const instance = typeahead.current;
```

But as for calling the methods, you are still going to get an error.  For whatever reason, these public methods which [exist on the class](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/src/core/Typeahead.js) are not documented [in the type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-bootstrap-typeahead/index.d.ts), so typescript doesn't know about them.

You may want to bring this up with any of the type maintainers or edit the `@types/react-bootstrap-typeahead` package yourself, as it seems to be an oversight.

But you can also expand the types with your own.

```
declare module "react-bootstrap-typeahead" {
    interface Typeahead<T extends TypeaheadModel> extends React.Component<TypeaheadProps<T>> {
        clear(): void;
        focus(): void;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that `typeahead` is not `null` before calling any methods.  The most concise way is with the optional chaining `?.`

```
const instance = typeahead.current;
instance?.clear();
instance?.focus();
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgG84AVATzFQAtUATOAXzjZcBIuhgBaAEYQIMAM4woKMOJhtOPMlSrckaADYoicEBG4BXfUhHEJ02QqUq17FFxTd8DKnF9xgAHYwSFCY6Nasru7cADxMcEgAHsEB3HLM6m48ALJmSPoAfAnJSKnpyGIAdADCuJABpTBxmdEACjhgcnEFRfQ%20fgMGqFAAFACUAFxwAG4QwNwUlAMDmBBo5nLjU7PziwN8VAeUVGgQAQrMSBcAvHDjcNe92kt%20p%20fwLhoeD4i2lWiiYLITDNKI8GIoAIsHrjRb9XxEGDmKABO7w5YxAro5Z%20UFfbjYnHLIiYa70T5ZDxHIk0-zca74SQoOTANCqFo8cQsgIAcys%20EJtMEwH0wSgACEWGSANoAcm4wBQ%20lqullABo4LKAigQEhZQBdalC5aBMDmGDtCCdMl9F7GokGZlyAByOqQU1lKBgimAknVgtpfCN9t8hkk%20QA0kgpfQRlaYMAzlNISwxg8igADAAk9HjiYClW1ur4GeDIbO1Q4kJ5SDJIzk%20T0wW4yahace3jtIcGZzkECslX0EB59cbGCQ3DGe27-DL9qIqRC2VK5gAksEQJWRdwF3W82d20URgH7TEFdMsV2ZxjzwVc2AE2dC26BL574%20Cw2MPm%20DEAPS3iexr-oBV7GmMc7Gvu5xkkg4BDiwSBIAAMsACiQUKDZWOO9L0AoXpIJUgRitqH5KsAABeXo-pep5-pE%20K0cBchgJCcCOnILpugyRg4AA7l4Fb6KyADWdaHp215vBcgT4QEaDWLcFLRP8yILjA07dtJ-aEUOI74LJMCQgp%20AaoZxlIFOQE4uZ8lIAA-P8VhGLC1kmu8FmOas6ybFZYE4kGBQxKAPJwHIUBoAyf68RAfGVHI0w8l4f5BX%20LGQkxOL-plcBjIcQA)

Comment: Solution with extending interface in module isn't working for `AsyncTypeahead`. Can anybody suggest solution please?